# C# CustomAttributeData class to attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, .net-4.8

I have the following code located in a `Swashbuckle.Swagger.IOperationFilter` class.

```cs
List<CustomAttributeData> controllerAttributes = apiDescription
    .ActionDescriptor
    .ControllerDescriptor
    .ControllerType
    .CustomAttributes
    .Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute))
    .ToList();
```

I am obtaining the collection successfully. I want to convert the collection `List<CustomAttributeData>` into a collection of my custom attribute `List<SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute>`.

[image]

I want to convert the `System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData` class to my custom attribute `SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute`.

---

Edit 1:
Here is how my `SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute` attribute looks like.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute : Attribute
{
    private ICollection<string> displayNames;

    public SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute()
    {
        this.DisplayNames = new List<string> { "File" };
    }

    public SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute(params string[] displayNames)
    {
        this.DisplayNames = displayNames;
    }

    public ICollection<string> DisplayNames
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.displayNames == null)
                return new List<string> { "File" };
            else
                return this.displayNames;
        }
        set => displayNames = value;
    }
}
```

After successfully converting the `List<CustomAttributeData>` to `List<SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute>` I'll be using the property shown in the class `SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute` named `DisplayNames`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First solution:

```cs
List<SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute> customControllerAttributes = apiDescription
    .ActionDescriptor
    .ControllerDescriptor
    .ControllerType
    .CustomAttributes
    .Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute))
    .Select(a =>
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<CustomAttributeTypedArgument> costuctorArgumentsReadOnlyCollection = (ReadOnlyCollection<CustomAttributeTypedArgument>)a.ConstructorArguments.Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        string[] contructorParams = costuctorArgumentsReadOnlyCollection?.ToArray().Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
        SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute myCustomAttr = (SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute)Activator.CreateInstance(a.AttributeType, contructorParams);
        return myCustomAttr;
    })
    .ToList();
```

*Explanation:* Both variables `costuctorArgumentsReadOnlyCollection` and `contructorParams` can be skipped in case the desired attribute has an empty constructor.

In that case, only this line will suffice:
`(SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute)Activator.CreateInstance(a.AttributeType, null);`

### Second solution:

This is a much cleaner solution. We can completely skip the `CustomAttributeData` class in the `IOperationFilter` like that:

```cs
List<SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute> controllerAttributes = apiDescription
    .ActionDescriptor
    .ControllerDescriptor
    .GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute>()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

After your `.Where`, add a select and translate as appropriate. The easiest would be, in your custom class, create a constructor that takes a `SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute` as the parameter and maps to your custom class as needed. Then your `Select` would be:

```
.Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute))
.Select(a => new CustomAttributeData(a))
.ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, my custom attribute named `SwaggerFileInFormDataAttribute` doesn't contain such constructor., where you can pass a `CustomAttributeData` parameter. This line `.Select(a => new CustomAttributeData(a))` doesn't work

Comment: I think you might have changed your question, or it is worded awkwardly. Are you translating from an existing type into a list of your own custom type, or vice versa? If you are converting into a list of your own custom type, add the constructor method. If vice versa, either create a method to assist with the conversion, or do it when you new up the class in your `select` (eg `a=>new Existing{Title = a.Title, Status = a.Status}` etc